# adding user list dropdown in customize theme

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

```
 $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control(
 $wp_customize, //Pass the $wp_customize object (required)
 'user_theme_name', //Set a unique ID for the control
 array(
    'label'      => __( 'Select Theme Name', 'user' ), //Admin-visible name of the control
    'description' => __( 'Using this option you can change the user' ),
    'settings'   => 'bootstrap_theme_name', //Which setting to load and manipulate (serialized is okay)
    'priority'   => 10, //Determines the order this control appears in for the specified section
    'section'    => 'user_options', //ID of the section this control should render in (can be one of yours, or a WordPress default section)
    'type'    => 'select',
    'choices' => array(
        'default' => 'admin',
        'cerulean' => 'Cerulean',
        'cosmo' => 'Cosmo',
        'cyborg' => 'cyborg',
    )
)
) );
```

I already created a dropdown menu in a customized theme but I can't get the  user list and put it in the dropdown menu. I try to add this  hook $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) ); and replace the choices in array object the $user but it did not show. i just want to get all user and put in on dropdown.

i need to display all users in dropdown
 [screenshot of the customize theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrPKi.png)

Comment: It might be a good idea to include the error for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution. I just add this hook to get the user in array format 
 $users = get_users();
 $user_names = wp_list_pluck( $users,'display_name' );

and change the 'choices' value to choices => $user_names